# Bash paste command output formatting

Tags: bash, paste

File1:

```
1
2
```

File2:

```
1 2 3
4 5
```

File3:

```
x x x
yy yy
zz
```

`paste file1 file2 file2` gives me a tab separated output:

```
1       1 2 3   x x x
2       4 5     yy yy
                zz
```

`paste -d" " file1 file2 file3` gives me the output:

```
1 1 2 3 x x x
2 4 5 yy yy
  zz
```

I want it like below:

```
1 1 2 3 x x x
2 4 5   yy yy
        zz
```

Any idea if this is possible or should I try any other command?

Comment: What about if the second line of `file2` is `4 5 6 7 8`? What's the desired output then? Is the goal here to have a column per input file?

Comment: The goal is to use space as a delimiter and still maintain the original formatting in each file. Sorry, I didn't get your question about file2.

Comment: So was your issue solved? It is not clear from your comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could use sed after to remove tabs

```
 paste file file2 file3 | sed 's/\t/ /'

 1 1 2 3 x x x
 2 4 5   yy yy
         zz
```

Here is a general purpose awk script that will work on any number of file with any formatting.

```
awk '
    {x=ARGIND;a[x]=a[x]>(b=length($0))?a[x]:b}
    {F[FNR,x]=$0}
    END{
            for(q=1;q<=FNR;q++)
            {
                    for(i=1;i<=ARGC;i++)
                    {
                    printf( "%-"a[i]"s ",F[q,i])
                    }print ""
            }
    }' file{1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: What if the files have tabs at EOL?

Comment: No, using unused delimiters would maintain box-like horizontal stacking.

Comment: @Jidder, Yes, this is what I wanted. In fact, I did try sed to substitute tabs with spaces, but used a "g" flag at the end, which messed up my output. I am using your solution now. Thanks.

Comment: @Ramesh the sed command will only work if the length of the first two files' lines add up to 8, as it still has a tab in it. The awk solution is far more durable. If fedorquis answer works for different lengths of lines/files, i would suggest accepting his.

Comment: I don't think I have fully understood what you are saying about the tabs, but, when I tried opening the generated output file (having .csv extension) in a spreadsheet application, I had to use both tab and space as field separators; using just the space as a filed separator would not place all the columns in a proper cell, and I think this is related to what you are saying. I will try fedorqui's solution with different input files, and use his solution instead, if it works out good for all the cases.

Comment: Okay, I opened the output file in vi, and I can see the file does has a few tabs, that explains why I have to use both tab and space field separators to correctly open it in spreadsheet application.

Comment: I tried the first solution with a table that on the first column had files with their paths, and a space was wrongly introduced in Documents: "/Users/BlaBla/Documen s/". It substituted the t for a space

Answer (score 4):

`paste` twice makes it to me:

```
$ paste <(paste -d" " f1 f2) f3
1 1 2 3 x x x
2 4 5   yy yy
        zz
```

Comment: How would this work for more files or different lengths of lines ?

Comment: It should be studied, but it is out of the scope of the question. It is nice that you covered it in your answer, but I don't see the need to generalize all the answers :D

Answer (score 2):

Just from you examples alone, it seems you could try first joining files 1 and 2, then joining that with file 3, but with a special delimiter, which you'd change later to a space.

Untested example:

```
paste -d" " file1 file2 | paste -d'|' - file3 | sed 's,|, ,g'
```

Here I used `|`, but you should use something you know for sure won't appear in the data i.e. something even more obscure like `˘`. A bit of a hack, but should work.

For just two files:

```
paste -d'¤' file1 file2 | sed 's,¤, ,g'
```

Comment: Actually, I am generating the paste command, and assigning it to a variable pastecmd, and executing it as ${pastecmd}, so this method is not suitable for me. There can be any number of files or at least one.

Comment: Not much of a hurdle, just generate the command to take two files and then loop over all of them. All this code and data can be contained in the same variable if you really need it there. But this is a different question already.

Comment: I tried it, but I have another issue now. When I execute the generated command using the syntax ${pastecmd}, the paste command thinks that the | is another input file. I tried to escape it, but no luck. I would rather prefer to explore paste command flags, and see this could be achievable. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try with a different delimiter like in the second example. You didn't mention saving code in variables in the question, so | was a poor default. Paste has no other useful flags, unfortunatelly.

Comment: @Ramesh Do not store a command in a variable. Use an array. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for more. That said you still can't stick a pipe in there as that still won't work.

Comment: @Etan Reisner, thanks for the link. I tried storing command in a variable for the first time as situations forced me.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

```
$ more file{1,2,3,4} | cat
::::::::::::::
file1
::::::::::::::
1
2
::::::::::::::
file2
::::::::::::::
1 2 3
4 5 6 7 8
::::::::::::::
file3
::::::::::::::
x x x
yy yy
zz
::::::::::::::
file4
::::::::::::::
a a a
bb bb bb
c c cc
d d d
$ paste file{1,2,3,4} | sed -e 's/\t/ \t/g' | column -t -s$'\t'
1   1 2 3       x x x   a a a
2   4 5 6 7 8   yy yy   bb bb bb
                zz      c c cc
                        d d d
```

Comment: No, I need the tabs between each files to be converted to a single space. I think, I can get the similar output as yours by using just the paste command without any flags.